# How do i integrate a Python Lambda Function into the Pipeline of AWS Amplify

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-amplify, aws-amplify-cli

So i'm trying to build an Ampliy application with Javascript and a Python Lambda function. Everything works just fine. I have setup my CodeCommit Branch for hosting with continous deployment. I add a API with a Lambda function in Python. With amplify push, amplify successfully deploys the corresponding API Gateway and Lambda and i can successfully interact with my lambda function. So, as soon as i  push my commits into my repository, the pipeline gets trigger and crashes during the build phase:

```
                                 # Starting phase: build
                                 # Executing command: amplifyPush --simple
2021-02-17T14:01:23.680Z [INFO]: [0mAmplify AppID found: d2l0j3vtlykp8l. Amplify App name is: documentdownload[0m
2021-02-17T14:01:23.783Z [INFO]: [0mBackend environment dev found in Amplify Console app: documentdownload[0m
2021-02-17T14:01:24.440Z [WARNING]: - Fetching updates to backend environment: dev from the cloud.
2021-02-17T14:01:24.725Z [WARNING]: ✔ Successfully pulled backend environment dev from the cloud.
2021-02-17T14:01:24.758Z [INFO]: 
2021-02-17T14:01:26.925Z [INFO]: [33mNote: It is recommended to run this command from the root of your app directory[39m
2021-02-17T14:01:31.904Z [WARNING]: - Initializing your environment: dev
2021-02-17T14:01:32.216Z [WARNING]: ✔ Initialized provider successfully.
2021-02-17T14:01:32.829Z [INFO]: [31mpython3 found but version Python 3.7.9 is less than the minimum required version.[39m
                                 [31mYou must have python >= 3.8 installed and available on your PATH as "python3" or "python". It can be installed from https://www.python.org/downloads[39m
                                 [31mYou must have pipenv installed and available on your PATH as "pipenv". It can be installed by running "pip3 install --user pipenv".[39m
2021-02-17T14:01:32.830Z [WARNING]: ✖ An error occurred when pushing the resources to the cloud
2021-02-17T14:01:32.830Z [WARNING]: ✖ There was an error initializing your environment.
2021-02-17T14:01:32.832Z [INFO]: [31minit failed[39m
2021-02-17T14:01:32.834Z [INFO]: [0mError: Missing required dependencies to package documentdownload[0m
                                 [0m    at Object.buildFunction (/root/.nvm/versions/node/v12.19.0/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/amplify-category-function/src/provider-utils/awscloudformation/utils/buildFunction.ts:21:11)[0m
                                 [0m    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)[0m
                                 [0m    at prepareResource (/root/.nvm/versions/node/v12.19.0/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/amplify-provider-awscloudformation/src/push-resources.ts:474:33)[0m
                                 [0m    at async Promise.all (index 0)[0m
                                 [0m    at Object.run (/root/.nvm/versions/node/v12.19.0/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/amplify-provider-awscloudformation/src/push-resources.ts:106:5)[0m
2021-02-17T14:01:32.856Z [ERROR]: !!! Build failed
2021-02-17T14:01:32.856Z [ERROR]: !!! Non-Zero Exit Code detected
2021-02-17T14:01:32.856Z [INFO]: # Starting environment caching...
2021-02-17T14:01:32.857Z [INFO]: # Environment caching completed
```

In the previous step PROVISION step is Python 3.8 though..

```
## Install python3.8
RUN wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.8.0/Python-3.8.0.tgz
RUN tar xvf Python-3.8.0.tgz
WORKDIR Python-3.8.0
RUN ./configure --enable-optimizations --prefix=/usr/local
RUN make altinstall
```

For now i have no idea why it behaves like this. Pushing the changes locally it works. Can anybody help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two Solutions from [here](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-console/issues/595):

1. swapping the build image This can be done with [this](https://hub.docker.com/r/nikolaik/python-nodejs) .Go to the Amplify Console, open the menu on the left, click on "Build Settings", scroll down until you see "Build Image Settings", on the drop-down select Custom, then enter the image name on the field just below it

2.If you want to build from a source like you mentioned: add the following to `amplify.yml` in the AWS console under App settings -> Build settings:

```yaml
backend:
  phases:
    preBuild:
      commands:
        - export BASE_PATH=$(pwd)
        - yum install -y gcc openssl-devel bzip2-devel libffi-devel python3.8-pip
        - cd /opt && wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.8.2/Python-3.8.2.tgz
        - cd /opt && tar xzf Python-3.8.2.tgz 
        - cd /opt/Python-3.8.2 && ./configure --enable-optimizations
        - cd /opt/Python-3.8.2 && make altinstall
        - pip3.8 install --user pipenv
        - ln -fs /usr/local/bin/python3.8 /usr/bin/python3
        - ln -fs /usr/local/bin/pip3.8 /usr/bin/pip3
        - cd $BASE_PATH
```

Comment: i wanted to experiment with that, but it seems apmlify does not use the amplify.yml file nor my updated version in the UI :( it responds with "Updating app: documentdownload success" yet when i try to redploy, the build step remains the same without the additional commands

Comment: how about `swapping` the build image?

Comment: i will try this out, do i have to build the container and upload it to ecr for example? or what is meant with the reference for a build image?

Comment: ok somehow amplify got confused with my different git branches. it finally pulled the amplify.yml file and your preBuild works, thank you!